# Which methods can be used to detect memory overwritten in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

If there are memory overwritten code such as buffer overflow in Linux kernel or driver, it's very hard to debug and find the root cause.

I know I can enable SLAB debug to get some information. If something is written to the slab memory after it is freed, then we will see warnings. But there is limitation for this method and we still can't get useful clues sometimes.

Are there any other kernel debugging method to detect memory overwritten?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Kmemcheck tool](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kmemcheck.txt). You may enable it in your kernel configuration and rebuild the kernel.

Kmemcheck may slow the system down significantly but it can detect incorrect memory accesses that would be very hard to find otherwise.

For the kernel 4.1 or newer on x86_64 architecture, [Kernel Address sanitizer (KASan)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kasan.txt) may also be an option. It should be much faster than Kmemcheck.